# Custom Tab bar in React Native

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to replicate something like the following in React native and React navigation. Having trouble getting started and even knowing if something like this would be possible. I got normal tabbed view working but, having trouble with this one. Any ideas on how it can be done are welcome. I am new to React Native.[image: I want to replicate this]

Comment: Do you want to do some kind of animation too while moving from one tab to another?

Comment: Yes animation would be better